# Split string values to integer in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, split

I have some different number in here. It changes every time. I need to create a multidimensional array like
`array[x][y]` => `x` should include value by splitting before `,` and `y` should include `' '` empty.
How can i do that ? Thank you.

```
dat.xyz
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

output = open('dat.xyz', 'r') # See the r
output_list = output.read().strip().split(',')
```

I can find number before `,` but it shows in just one line. However, I want to do that multidimensional. It should split dimension to see empty `' '`. Thank you.

Output should be following

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should split first around spaces to get rows and then iterate on those rows to get the cells:

```
>>> rows = "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9".split(' ')
>>> rows
['2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', '2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', '2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', '2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9']
>>> [row.split(',') for row in rows]
[['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']]
```

You could also convert those cells to integers:

```
>>> [[int(cell) for cell in row.split(',')] for row in rows]
[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

or let [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) do the conversion for you:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([row.split(',') for row in rows], np.int)
array([[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: Result is exactly what i want. But, what is row.split. Row is unknown here ? It gives some error. Also i read rows in my text file. Therefore just .split doesnot work. I should use something like that rows.read().strip().split(' '). Can you edit your code according to if i take it in  a text file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

# read file and split over whitespace
with open('dat.xyz', 'r') as f:
    rows = f.read()
    rows = rows.split(' ')

arr = []

# split each value in row over comma, then convert each element to integer
for row in rows:
    row = row.split(',')
    for i in range(len(row)):
        row[i] = int(row[i])
    arr.append(row)

# convert to array
arr = np.array(arr)

arr
```

Output:

```
array([[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```